# Want to attach click event with specific hyperlink

Tags: jquery

i know how to attach click event with hyperlink...here is sample code

```
$(".notice").click(function() {
   alert("Hello world!");
});
```

here is my hyperlink html

```
<a href="http://www.bba-reman.com/catalogue/DetailedProduct.aspx?DetailedProduct=2382"><img border="0" src="http://bba-reman.com/images/order_online.gif"></a>
```

in my case hyperlink has no id and class but this part in href is fixed

```
http://www.bba-reman.com/catalogue/DetailedProduct.aspx & this part is variable
?DetailedProduct=2382
```

so i want to attach click event with those hyperlink which is associated with this url in its href `http://www.bba-reman.com/catalogue/DetailedProduct.aspx`

can u help me to do it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 $("a[href^='http://www.bba-reman.com/catalogue/DetailedProduct.aspx']").click(function() {
     alert("Hello world!");
     return false;  //To stop propogation
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WKz78/